# CSS: Image moves in safari when div expands

Tags: css, html

I have an ajax search suggestions implemented on my site, and it works smoothly on chrome.
That's how it should look, and that's how it looks on chrome:

[image]

However, on Safari, the search image jumps down:

[image]

Here's my HTML for the div:

```
<div class ='searchBox'>
<form>
<input id = 'searchInput' type = 'text' placeholder = 'Search'> 
<img id = 'goSearch' class ='sprites'/>
<div class = 'liveSearch'></div>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
 .mainContainer .sideContainer .searchBox{
    margin-top:2%;
    background-color:rgb(188, 190, 192);
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.125em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.125em;
    padding-bottom:10%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:220px;
    letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
 }
 .mainContainer .sideContainer .searchBox #searchInput{
    letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
    background: rgb(241, 242, 242);
    color: rgb(109, 110, 113);
    font-size: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.125em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.125em;
    border:#aaaaaa 0.0625em solid;
    width:75%;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-left:2px;
    height:21px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
    position:relative;
    min-width:75%;
    margin-top:5%;
    left:5%;
    font-family: 'utsaah';
 }
 .mainContainer .sideContainer .searchBox #goSearch{
    width:28px;
    height:28px;
    left:82%;
    margin-top:5%;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
 .mainContainer .sideContainer .searchBox #goSearch:hover{
    background-position:-0px -38px;
 }
 .mainContainer .sideContainer .searchBox .liveSearch{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: rgb(188, 190, 192);
    width:73%;
    left:5.5%;
    position:relative;
  }
```

How can I make it so that it wouldn't jump around? Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not try, (i dont have an osx safari) But i met nearly same problem earlyer in other browsers and this fixed the problem:

```
   #searchInput, #goSearch{
       position: static;
       display: inline-block; /*and this may needed */
       vertical-align: top; /*and this*/
       margin: 0px;
   }
```

I think the absolute positionong is not needed for these two elements.
If this not helps i delete this comment. This was only an idea.

Comment: `position:static` did make it so it wouldn't move, but now how can I move the button around? Because margin-top, moves the search bar too, padding-top does not display correctly with CSS sprites, and top does not work with static position.